# What is the difference between constant and constant reference argument

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, constants

I have seen many people set their function argument as:

```
function(const myType &myObj)
```

I do not understand why they use `&` after the type?

It seems `const` is enough to stop the constructor from being called.

So, I wrote the following code and I see no advantage in the result. Can someone explain that?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class myclass
{
public:

    myclass()
    {
        cout<<"constructor is called\n";
    }

    int field;
};

void func1(myclass a)
{
    cout<<"func1: "<<a.field<<"\n";
}


void func2(const myclass a)
{
    cout<<"func2: "<<a.field<<"\n";
}


void func3(const myclass &a)
{
    cout<<"func3: "<<a.field<<"\n";
}

int main ()
{
    myclass obj;
    obj.field=3;
    cout<<"----------------\n";
    func1(obj);
    cout<<"----------------\n";
    func2(obj);
    cout<<"----------------\n";
    func3(obj);
    cout<<"----------------\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
constructor is called
----------------
func1: 3
----------------
func2: 3
----------------
func3: 3
----------------
```

Comment: This is not about default constructor, it's about [copy constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor), which in your case is [generated automatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three). Please take a look at [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: `const` has nothing to do with whether a constructor is called

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So, I wrote the following code and I see no advantage in the result. Can someone explain that?

The problem is you never set your copy constructor to output anything to see if a copy is made.  If we add

```
myclass( const myclass & foo) : field(foo.field)
{
    cout<<"copy constructor is called\n";
}
```

The output will be

```
constructor is called
----------------
copy constructor is called
func1: 3
----------------
copy constructor is called
func2: 3
----------------
func3: 3
----------------
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/79abc1d236011a08)</kbd>

As you can see copies are made if you do not pass by reference.

---

The only difference between

```
void func1(myclass a)
```

and

```
void func2(const myclass a)
```

Is that `a` is `const` in the second example. There really is no reason to do this though; since it is a copy, it doesn't matter if you change it or not. If you have a function that can use a `const` object, then I suggest passing by `const &` to avoid copies as long as copying is more expensive than a reference (non-pod types, which are bigger than the size of a pointer).

Comment: It matters for the sake of optimization though.

Comment: for primitive types passing by reference may be slower than copying

Comment: @NathanOliver, do you ask me to enumerate all the optimizations that become possible in constant context?

Answer (score 2):

> It seems const is enough to stop the constructor from being called.

If you use just `const` and no `&`, copy constructor is called. Using `const &` guarantees no new copy of objects are made.

As pointed in the comments below: the reason you are not seeing the output is because you never logged the invocation copy constructors. Putting print in destructor of the class would be perhaps a better idea to see the effect.

Comment: Most of your answer is talking about copy elision which has nothing at all to do with this question

Answer (score 2):

Add in the class members:

```
myclass(myclass const &)
{
    cout<<"copy constructor is called\n";
}

~myclass()
{
    cout<<"destructor is called\n";
}
```

and then, after inspecting the new output, re-evaluate your position on what effect the `&` has.